# CSS Header Stretch – What am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css, header, stretch

I'm trying to get a handle on CSS. Wanting to have the background image for the header stretch to fill the width of the page.

Have tried `background-size: cover;` but it doesn't seem to be working.

What am I doing wrong?

Codepen: http://codepen.io/jacobdw/pen/mOjozZ

HTML:

```
<DOCTYPE! HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Development Resources</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Space+Mono" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <h1>Development Resources</h1>
    </header>

    <section class="container">

        <article>
            <h2>News/Blogs</h2>

                <h3>Web Design</h3>

                    <ul>
                         <li><a href="http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/">Web Designer Depot</a></li>
                         <li><a href="http://www.instantshift.com/">Instant Shift</a></li>
                         <li><a href="http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/">Hong Kiat</a></li>
                         <li><a href="https://www.smashingmagazine.com/" title="e.g. 'Information about the company ...">Smashing Magazine</a></li>
                         <li><a href="http://www.vandelaydesign.com">Vandelay Design</a></li>
                         <li><a href="http://thenextweb.com/">The Next Web</a></li>
                         <li><a href="https://speckyboy.com/">Speckyboy</a></li>
                    </ul>
        </article>

        <article>
            <h2>Courses</h2>
                <ul>
                     <li><a href="https://www.lynda.com/">Lynda</a></li>
                     <li><a href="https://dash.generalassemb.ly/">Dash | General Assembly</a></li>
                     <li><a href="https://www.freecodecamp.com">FreeCodeCamp</a></li>
                     <li><a href="https://www.codecademy.com/">Code Academy</a></li>
                </ul>
        </article>


        <article>
            <h2>References</h2>

                <h3>General</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/">MDN</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.w3schools.com/">w3schools</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://jgthms.com/web-design-in-4-minutes/">Web Design in 4 Minutes</a></li>
                    </ul>

                <h3>HTML</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="https://css-tricks.com/examples/CleanCode/Beautiful-HTML.png">What Beautiful HTML Looks Like</a></li>
                    </ul>
                <h3>CSS</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp">W3 Schools CSS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://css-tricks.com/">CSS-Tricks</li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.dustindiaz.com/css-shorthand/">CSS Shorthand</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/">Listamatic</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.noupe.com/essentials/freebies-tools-templates/css-typography-contrast-techniques-tutorials-and-best-practices.html">CSS Typography Contrast Techniques</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.alvit.de/css-showcase/css-navigation-techniques-showcase.php">CSS Navigation Techniques Showcase</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://odyniec.net/articles/turning-lists-into-trees/">Turning Lists into Trees</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://alistapart.com/article/multicolumnlists">Multi-column Lists</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://3.7designs.co/blog/2008/06/10-examples-of-beautiful-css-typography-and-how-they-did-it/">10 Examples of Beautiful CSS Typography</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/">CSS Specificity Things You Should Know</a></li>
                    </ul>
        </article>

        <article>
            <h2>Tips</h2>

                <h3>CSS</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS">Writing Efficient CSS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2009/05/10-best-css-practices-to-improve-your-code/">10 Best CSS Practices to Improve Your Code</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/5-ways-to-instantly-write-better-css--net-3003">5 Ways to Instantly Write Better CSS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://erraticwisdom.com/2006/01/18/5-tips-for-organizing-your-css">5 Tips for Organising Your CSS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/05/improving-code-readability-with-css-styleguides/">Improving Code Readability with CSS Style Guides</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/typographic-contrast-flow">Typography Contrast</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://designreviver.com/tips/13-training-principles-of-css-everyone-should-know/">13 Training Principles of CSS Everyone Should Know</a></li>
                    </ul>
        </article>


        <article>
            <h2>Tools</h2>

                <h3>CSS</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://www.cssmatic.com/">CSSMatic</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.accessify.com/tools-and-wizards/developer-tools/list-o-matic/">List-o-matic</a></li>
                    </ul>
        </article>


        <article>
            <h2>Other</h2>
                <h3>Code Editors</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="https://github.com/">Github</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://codepen.io/">Codepen</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://jsfiddle.net/">JSFiddle</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <h3>Communities</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Stackoverflow</a></li>
                    </ul>
        </article>


    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
header {
    background-color: #263d36;
    background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/90807/pexels-photo-90807.jpeg");
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    line-height: 1.2;
    padding: 10vw 2em;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

header h1 {
    color: white;
    background: black;
    padding: 50px 10px;
}

body {
    color: #555;
    font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 920px;
    padding: 30px 20px;
}


h1, h2, strong {
    color: #333;
}

a { 
    color: firebrick
}

ul {
    border-left: 1px solid #555;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```

Comment: What are you talking about? The image is the width of the container. You have a set width on `<body>` - if you want it to stretch to the width of the window, you will have to remove the width on body.

Comment: In my eyes, it's not stretch. LoL. maybe you have a good eyes, did you tried using an image instead of background? if it is an image, you can do flexbox in css.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the width from your body or set it to auto like so:

```css
body {
    color: #555;
    font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    padding: 30px 20px;
}
```

If you want the content positioned the same as before, try adding:

```css
.container {
  width: 920px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given padding and width to body, remove that:

```css
body {
    color: #555;
    font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 920px; /* remove this */
    padding: 30px 20px;/* make this 0px */
}
```

---

One more tip for CodePen:

In your HTML section you write only those things which you want inside `body` tag of your HTML, not the whole HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cut next styles:

```
 margin: 0 auto;
    width: 920px;
    padding: 30px 20px;
```

From body, and apply it to the container class.